# How to unblock specific IP addresses from AWS WAF

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

As a user you can get the list of blocked ip's: `aws wafv2 get-rate-based-statement-managed-keys --scope=REGIONAL --region=region --web-acl-name=WebACLName --web-acl-id=WebACLId --rule-name=RuleName`

But how do we specifically remove an ip from this list?
Is there an option other than whitelisting the ip completely?

Comment: You can either [delete](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/wafv2/delete-ip-set.html) the IP set, or [update](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/wafv2/update-ip-set.html) it.

Comment: AWS WAF will create an IP set with blocked IPs automatically upon violating a rule?

Comment: Create a whitelist and add that IP.

Answer (score 0):

This command returns list of IPs blocked by a rate-based rule. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/listing-managed-ips.html

It is not possible remove IP from this list by yourself, but it is automatically removed after the rate from this IP falls bellow the limit you set in your rule.

> When the rule action triggers, AWS WAF applies the action to additional requests from the IP address until the request rate falls below the limit. It can take a minute or two for the action change to go into effect.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rule-statement-type-rate-based.html

Answer (score 0):

To remove an IP from the list of blocked IPs you can use the aws wafv2 update-rate-based-statement-managed-keys command. This command allows you to specify which IPs should be removed from the list of blocked IPs. You can also use the aws wafv2 delete-rate-based-statement-managed-key command to delete a specific IP from the list. Either of these can be used to remove an IP from the list without whitelisting it completely.

Answer (score -2):

If you dont want to whitelist, then stop flooding request from that I to your resource

The ratebased rule is man

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).